# Is it possible to extract only the key part while looping?

Tags: javascript

I have got the above key value pair structure

While looping is it possible to extract only the key

```
var list_of_stocks= {
  "CBB": "Communications",
  "VZ": "Communications",
  "UPS": "Transportation"
};
for (var key in list_of_stocks) {
console.log(list_of_stocks[0]);
}
```

So that the output will look like

```
CBB
VZ
UPS
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n3fmw1mw/207/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just log `key`:

```js
var list_of_stocks= {
      "CBB": "Communications",
      "VZ": "Communications",
      "UPS": "Transportation",
      "RRTS": "Transportation",
      "AAC": "Heath"
};
for (var key in list_of_stocks) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Want an array of keys? Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
var list_of_stocks= {
  "CBB": "Communications",
  "VZ": "Communications",
  "UPS": "Transportation",
  "RRTS": "Transportation",
  "AAC": "Heath"
};

var keys = Object.keys(list_of_stocks);

console.log(keys);
console.log(keys[0]); //CBB
```

Comment: Thank you , but still is it possible to extract using list_of_stocks ??

Comment: For example , list_of_stocks[0].1= CBB

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Define `extract`.

Comment: Do you want an array of keys?

Comment: Similarly is it possible to get values also ?? I mean Communications

Comment: @PreethiJain, I highly recommend you get used to simple google searches. "javascript Object values to array" yields this result: [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).  (Everything in this question could have been answered within the top few results)